# to pick latest file based on file name having dd-mm-yyyy hh:m:s in linux

Tags: linux

We have few files as below

```
employee.arya-date-01-1-2022-time-22:42:00.txt.csv
employee.arya-date-02-1-2022-time-16:29:00.txt.csv
employee.arya-date-02-1-2022-time-19:35:00.txt.csv
employee.arya-date-03-1-2022-time-7:12:00.txt.csv
employee.arya-date-04-1-2022-time-16:33:00.txt.csv
employee.arya-date-04-1-2022-time-2:23:00.txt.csv
employee.arya-date-04-1-2022-time-7:2:00.txt.csv
employee.arya-date-29-1-2022-time-7:2:00.txt.csv
```

Based on the file name : the latest file will be "`employee.arya-date-29-1-2022-time-7:2:00.txt.csv`" but when i try to run a command as below , unable to pick the latest file getting as "`employee.arya-date-04-1-2022-time-7:1:00.txt.csv`"

tried command: but not working:

```
ls employee.arya-*|sort -r|head -1
```

is there any way to get latest file. I tried all the options in ls and sort and none of them is working. Can any one pls suggest

Comment: What is not working? Why should `...23-1-2022` be the latest file? Did you consider `sort`'s key options?

Comment: @RudiC .. Thanks for the reply. I tried and its picking other file but not latest file

Comment: sorry , a typo in the file name. I just modified my question

Comment: What file did it pick? Did you consider `sort`'s `key` (-k) option? Details, and precision, please. With your cited command, it gives me the `...23-2-2022-xyz-11:34:14...` file.

Comment: @RudiC Its picking : employee.arya-date-04-1-2022-time-7:1:00.txt.csv . I just added more file names .

Comment: @steeldriver thank you. i corrected it

Comment: if you change the timestamps in the names to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, the problem turns trivial...

Comment: your files have a create-time ! why not listing by time reversed `ls -tr empl*|head -1` ?

Comment: @Yunus  for this i am getting output as employee.arya-date-01-1-2022-time-22:54:00.txt.csv   but its older one

Comment: @Yunus they probably don't have a create time; it's far more likely they've only a last-modified time

Comment: @Arya `ls -t ` will list the newest or *last modified , `ls -tr` does the inverse! Remove the r flag in your case to get the newest file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick script that does the job.

(Note: I changed this to make it more locale-neutral, but it still may not work with all locales; edit the `timestamp=` line if `date` for you accepts a different format.)

```
#!/bin/bash
latest=''
latesttimestamp=0
for file in employee.arya-* ; do
    # remove everything up to -date-
    datetime="${file#*-date-}"
    # remove .txt.csv
    datetime="${datetime%.txt.csv}"
    # get the time (after -time-)
    time="${datetime#*-time-}"
    # get the date (before -time-)
    date="${datetime%-time-*}"
    # get the day
    dd="${datetime%%-*}"
    # get the month and year
    mmyy="${date#*-}"
    mm="${mmyy%-*}"
    yyyy="${mmyy#*-}"
    # get the timestamp for that datetime
    timestamp="$(date --date="$yyyy/$mm/$dd $time" +'%s')"
    # compare to latest found so far
    if [[ "$timestamp" -gt "$latesttimestamp" ]] ; then
        latest="$file"
        latesttimestamp="$timestamp"
    fi
done
echo "$latest"
```

Save that as `latestfile.sh` or whatever, somewhere in your `$PATH`. Make it executable (`chmod a+x latestfile.sh`), and then `latestfile.sh` does the trick.

(You could also make it into a shell function nearly as easily if you prefer.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. but as per my file names i have provided until 4th Jan. But if i have 28 Jan its getting failed as "invalid date"

Comment: @Arya Sorry, I'm a dumb American and for some reason thought it was `mm-dd` rather than `dd-mm`. I changed the script above to parse the date fully, but depending on your locale, you may need to change the `timestamp=` line to something your version of `date` accepts; hopefully with the edits it's clear how.

Comment: thanks for the response. Approched helpmed me.